# Is the matrix that represents a self-adjoint operator always real?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently studying linear-algebra and I was asking myself:
If f is a self-adjoint operator of a euclidean space, is the matrix that represents f always real?

Comment: The eigenvalues of the matrix are always real, the elements need not be real.

Comment: Yes, in my book, there's a proof of the fact that all the eigenvalues of such a matric are real, and they use the fact that the matrix is real

Comment: By definition a Euclidean vector space is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, hence a linear operator is represented by a real matrix. This has nothing to do with self-adjoint.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Wait, isn't it just that since $f=f^*$, A is real? (on top of the fact that it's an operator of a euclidean space?)

Comment: I think “Euclidean space” always means that it is real, not complex. Every linear operator (or better: its matrix representation) of this has real entries. The property that it is self-adjoint means that the matrix is symmetric and therefore has only real Eigenvalues.

Comment: If we consider complex numbers, then let $f$ be represented by $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-i\\i&1\end{bmatrix}$, clearly $f=f^*$, $A=A^*$, but $A$ is not real (though it has real eigenvalues 0 and 2)